# setSelected(true) not work on custom view

Tags: android, android-view, android-gridview

I have created custom View called **Color**. I use object of Color to fill GridView (same issue is in ListView also).

My task is to let user choose one color and highlight it.

Previously I do something like that but I used only in building widgets and everything worked. This time I use my own.

This cose is for item clicking:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    int color = (int)id;

    Log.d(TAG, "Selected color: " + id);
    view.setSelected(true);
    view.invalidate();
}
```

Color.onDraw:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (isSelected()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "color draw selected");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "not selected " + color);
    }
}
```

Also I set `setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);` to this GridView (`AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` don't help also)

In log I see:

```
Selected color: 8355711
not selected 16711680
not selected 16743680
not selected 8355711
```

I am sure, Color items is not recreating more than on time.

I tried change GridView to ListView, user default widget (overrided only onDraw()). Nothing helps. Maybe I forgot something?

In my opinion GridView somehow drop selected status.

If you need more info just tell.

Addition:

I checked with debugger. View with color 8355711 is same object in both functions.

I used setOnItemSelectedListener(this); to track item selection. But nothing happen in this listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this issue my self by making my own select. Its workaround.

In Color class added:

```
private boolean selected = false;

public boolean isSelected2() {
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected2(boolean selected) {
    this.selected = selected;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { 
    ....        
    if (isSelected2()) {
        //draw selected state
    } else {
    ....
}
```

On ColorChooser grid:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    ...
    int i = getChildCount();
    while (--i >= 0)
        ((Color)getChildAt(i)).setSelected2(false);

    ((Color)view).setSelected2(true);
    ....
}
```

Reason why I not to override natice `setSelected(boolean state)` is some other code in grid every time make all items in deselected state. I don't know why, because in other places same more native code work very fine.

Answer (score 2):

The method [isSelected()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isSelected%28%29) is comming from the GridView which is a child of View.

Basically when calling `isSelected()` you're saying: "is the gridview selected" which is not what you want.

What you want is: "is there any selected view in the grid view ?"

Which could be achieved using [getSelectedView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getSelectedView%28%29)

As the documentation says, you will get a reference to the selected view or `null` if none is selected.

Also make sur your GridView is properly initialized to handle item selection.

**EDIT :** Ok i understand that isSelected() is called from the Color view. My first guess is then useless.

But I think you should try to make your item selected using the [setSelection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#setSelection%28int%29) of the GridView object.

Add something like:

```
myGridView.setSelection(position);
```

Comment: isSelected() I call for child of GridView. How I can determine GridView is properly initialized? I think here will be issue.

Comment: Ha ok, sorry for missunderstanding. Let me check that out.

Comment: Did you try to long press the items in order to call the default onItemLongClick behavior ?

Comment: I used setOnItemSelectedListener(this); to track selections, but nothing happen...

Comment: how it can help me? What is default long click behavior?

Comment: I was just thinking about a way to understand what's going on. I just updated my answer.

Comment: myGridView.setSelection(position); dont help.